# How do one store data in a block?

Tags: substrate

My use case is very simple. I want to create a chain where peers can store some public data. What is the best way to accomplish that in Substrate?

I think I should implement a custom run time for that, but I'm not sure how to create a transaction sending data. I didn't found anything on that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may be looking for something like the system module's [`remark`](https://substrate.dev/rustdocs/master/palette_system/enum.Call.html#variant.remark) transaction.

It allows users to submit arbitrary pieces of data and have them attested to by the blockchain. That feature is available in any Substrate based blockchain including the [node template](https://github.com/substrate-developer-hub/substrate-node-template).

A good place to start learning how to build custom runtimes and explore your idea more is the [Proof of Existence](https://substrate.dev/docs/en/next/tutorials/creating-your-first-substrate-chain/) tutorial.